I am getting these error everytime I try to run the react and node based code in my system , tried "reinstalling npm install" and everything
So we are working on this project of a website using MERN stack with mongodb but everytime i tried running the code that my friend provides me it gives this error. Checked the vite dependencies but no luck so I am gonna drop the list of dependencies here.
The error:
PS C:\Users\shish\OneDrive\Desktop\Working codes\30 Sept codes\24 Sep 2024\virtualr-main> npm run dev

> virtualr@0.0.0 dev
> vite

failed to load config from C:\Users\shish\OneDrive\Desktop\Working codes\30 Sept codes\24 Sep 2024\virtualr-main\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\shish\OneDrive\Desktop\Working codes\30 Sept codes\24 Sep 2024\virtualr-main\node_modules\react-refresh\cjs\react-refresh-runtime.development.js'
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:448:20)
    at file:///C:/Users/shish/OneDrive/Desktop/Working%20codes/30%20Sept%20codes/24%20Sep%202024/virtualr-main/node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react/dist/index.mjs:17:6
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24)
    at async loadConfigFromBundledFile (file:///C:/Users/shish/OneDrive/Desktop/Working%20codes/30%20Sept%20codes/24%20Sep%202024/virtualr-main/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CDnG8rE7.js:66634:15)
    at async loadConfigFromFile (file:///C:/Users/shish/OneDrive/Desktop/Working%20codes/30%20Sept%20codes/24%20Sep%202024/virtualr-main/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CDnG8rE7.js:66475:24)
    at async resolveConfig (file:///C:/Users/shish/OneDrive/Desktop/Working%20codes/30%20Sept%20codes/24%20Sep%202024/virtualr-main/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CDnG8rE7.js:66083:24)
    at async _createServer (file:///C:/Users/shish/OneDrive/Desktop/Working%20codes/30%20Sept%20codes/24%20Sep%202024/virtualr-main/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-CDnG8rE7.js:62701:18)
    at async CAC.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/shish/OneDrive/Desktop/Working%20codes/30%20Sept%20codes/24%20Sep%202024/virtualr-main/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:735:20)

Package.json:
{
  "name": "virtualr",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@google/generative-ai": "^0.17.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.16.7",
    "@mui/material": "^5.16.7",
    "axios": "^1.7.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.4",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
    "chatgpt-api": "^0.0.6",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "lucide-react": "^0.344.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.5.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.52.2",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "daisyui": "^4.12.10",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  }
}


Tried everything that generically comes on web or gpt but getting these error continuously. Want the solution to run my code.

Well, does that file exist?  It's a very long path, but it's still under the 260-character limit.

No, I just checked and the "cjs" at second last of that path is empty there is no file as react-refresh-runtime.development.js' . WHAT SHOULD I DO ?

Did you npm install react-refresh?

Yes , these type of error occurred after running the localhost
node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^
[Failed to load PostCSS config: Failed to load PostCSS config (searchPath: C:/Users/shish/OneDrive/Desktop/Working codes/30 Sept codes/24 Sep 2024/virtualr-main): [Error] Loading PostCSS Plugin failed: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\shish\OneDrive\Desktop\Working codes\30 Sept codes\24 Sep 2024\virtualr-main\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Try these below steps:

Delete node_modules and Reinstall Dependencies
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install

Check Vite Plugin for React
npm install @vitejs/plugin-react

Ensure react-refresh is installed
npm install react-refresh

Update both Vite and React
npm update vite react react-dom

If the project is in OneDrive, it can sometimes cause path issues. Try moving the project to a local directory (e.g., C:\Projects\virtualr) and then run:
npm install
npm run dev

Ensure the vite.config.js is correctly configured for React.


